# freeglut(empty): failed to open display

Tags: c++, terminal, sdk, ubuntu-20.04

I want to make Rivermax SDK app (media_receiver) run on Ubuntu 20.04
but when glutInit() is called, it says like title !
anyone have any ideas?

I've tried to run an example out of app , i got display on screen
but when i run the app , nothing changed

Comment: Have you already searched the web? If I copy/paste your title to google literally I get many of promising hits...

Comment: i saw them but it may not be similar to my environment. i also tried sth but nothing works